# How to hide query string URL in Struts 2

Tags: spring-mvc, url, servlets, struts2, query-string

How to Hide query string URL in Struts 2.

We are using third party URL , when we hit the URL it open a PDF, we want to hide some parameters in query string URL.
In the URL there pass invoice number and Date both parameter we want to hide , when we hit url in any ways.

If we cannot hide the using query string while using URL tag? What is the alternative for the above scenario?

URL:  `http://dart.corp.xerox.com/WorkplaceXCS/GetDocument?DocumentClass=INV&invno=086664659&invdt=11/01/2016`

Comment: The only way to hide a query from the client is to run it on the server and send the results back to the browser. You could use a POST, but the request is still trivially retrievable from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form tag and hide a parameter with the hidden input field then use URL with the parameter like in following answer.

[This is the answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25593596/573032)

> You can add a form to trigger a form submit event instead of default link's `click` event. A form should contain a hidden field to hold a parameter value. Then add javascript code to handle `click` event.
>
> ```
> <s:url action="custACDetails" includeContext="false" var="urlTag"/>
> <s:set var="contextPath">${pageContext.request.contextPath}</s:set>
> <s:a id="acno" href="%{#contextPath+#urlTag}"><s:property value="acno"/></s:a>
> <s:form id="form" action="%{#urlTag}" method="POST">
>   <s:hidden name="yourAc" value="%{acno}"/>
> </s:form>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   $(document).ready(function() {
>     $("#acno").click(function(e) {
>       e.preventDefault();
>       $("#form").submit();
>     });
>   });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Above code is not working , url is not hiding in this case.